# What does a black and white texture look like after converting it to vectors?

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, mathematics, vector

Is my guess that I showed in the picture below correct?

If not, what's the best way to represent a group of vectors emerging from a black and white texture?

[image]

Comment: I just want to point out that Color doesn't give you black and white... Fac will give you black and white, Color will give you random colors (in shaders, not sure if in gn as well)

Answer (score 4):

> what's the best way to represent a group of vectors emerging from a black and white texture?

Shader

[image]

---

Geo

[image]

---

Result

[image]

Answer (score 3):

as you can see in this simple setup, your assumption is wrong.

Color is RGB -> so if you plug this in a vector it gets xyz.

Noise give us a value from 0 to 1 (and looks like that it is a different for each rgb/xyz). And as this test shows:

[image]

And here the same test, but just setting absolute positions:

[image]

With this node setup you can see, from which position in grid the position will be change to the noise position.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Now I see vectors from Texture like this - https://ibb.co/FbdL3vk
Am I closer to the truth?)

Comment: Almost. x, y and z have all different values for each point.

Comment: It seems that in my drawing I wanted to show this - that each point has RGB info that converted into XYZ info ( i.e. vector ) when translated into a vector.

It's just that the black and white texture has points with vector where X=Y=Z. Is it so?

Comment: This is true, if you take the fac value (which is just a float). But if you take the color value, it is different for x, y and z. And in your provided image in the question, you took the color value. so...it is different as i wrote in my answer.